# Why does row have a negative gutter but row-fluid does not?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6cL3znc/1/)

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span4">regular row</div>
      <div class="span8">regular row 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span4">fluid row</div>
      <div class="span8">fluid row 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm [reading](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) about how bootstrap has a gutter system with negative margins. This does not seem to apply to row-fluid.  I see row-fluid has 0 margin styles.  Why?

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you actually using? Your markup is for *[v2](https://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/)* but your jsFiddle is linked to *[v3](https://getbootstrap.com/css/)* resources: *v2* and *v3* use a different syntax as far as columns/rows are concerned (_row-fluid does not exist in v3_).

Comment: @vanburen - Thanks that was it

Comment: No problem and glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row-fluid` is a Bootstrap 2 class.  In Bootstrap 3 `row-fluid` was [replaced](http://getbootstrap.com/migration/) by `row`.  If you use `row-fluid` in Bootstrap 3 as I did then no bootstrap style will be applied to the element.  That's why there is no negative margin.